# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL create table index

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

I am trying to create a table and I am getting an error, I don’t know why. I thought it was because of the float, but my Field table has a float and is being generated correctly.

I was trying to change dialect or create-drop property. But it does not help me. So i really don’t know what to do.

Also, I thought column rank is cause of error, but i don't know why

Error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table index (id integer not null, lemma_id integer not null, page_id integer not null, rank float not null, primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at loader.Loader.main(Loader.java:22)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index (id integer not null, lemma_id integer not null, page_id integer not null,' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:762)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:646)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 11 more
```

Hibernate cfg

```
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/search_engine?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">roottoor</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>

        <mapping class="loader.scanner.Website"></mapping>
        <mapping class="loader.entity.Field"></mapping>
        <mapping class="loader.entity.Lemma"></mapping>
        <mapping class="loader.entity.Index"></mapping>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Index entity

```
package loader.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(
        name = "index"
)
public class Index {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(
            name = "page_id",
            nullable = false
    )
    private int pageId;

    @Column(
            name = "lemma_id",
            nullable = false
    )
    private int lemmaId;

    @Column(
            nullable = false
    )
    private float rank;

    public Index(int pageId, int lemmaId, float rank) {
        this.pageId = pageId;
        this.lemmaId = lemmaId;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public Index(){

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getPageId() {
        return pageId;
    }

    public void setPageId(int pageId) {
        this.pageId = pageId;
    }

    public int getLemmaId() {
        return lemmaId;
    }

    public void setLemmaId(int lemmaId) {
        this.lemmaId = lemmaId;
    }

    public float getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(float rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Index{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", pageId=" + pageId +
                ", lemmaId=" + lemmaId +
                ", rank=" + rank +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index and rank are reserved keywords in SQL. Try changing it to something else.

But if you want to use index only then use below.

```
@Table(name = "\"index\"")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried to change table name, columns names it doesn’t help

Comment: Even rank is a keyword.

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't think about changing both names

Comment: Yes it is, thank you. I changed the name of the table and column Rank as you said so it works!